Deriving the Inclusion-Exclusion Formula
I am trying to derive the Inclusion-Exclusion formula from scratch.
Suppose I have three sets A, B, and C- this is a well known formula (e.g venn diagrams, removing the double counted areas):
$$ |A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C| $$
For four sets, I tried to write out each part:
$$ |A \cup B \cup C \cup D| = |A| + |B| + |C| + |D| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |A \cap D| - |B \cap C| - |B \cap D| - |C \cap D| + |A \cap B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap D| + |A \cap C \cap D| + |B \cap C \cap D| - |A \cap B \cap C \cap D| $$
And for five sets A, B, C, D, and E:
$$ |A \cup B \cup C \cup D \cup E| = $$
$$ |A| + |B| + |C| + |D| + |E| $$
$$ - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |A \cap D| - |A \cap E| - |B \cap C| - |B \cap D| - |B \cap E| - |C \cap D| - |C \cap E| - |D \cap E| $$
$$ + |A \cap B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap D| + |A \cap B \cap E| + |A \cap C \cap D| + |A \cap C \cap E| + |A \cap D \cap E| + |B \cap C \cap D| + |B \cap C \cap E| + |B \cap D \cap E| + |C \cap D \cap E| $$
$$ - |A \cap B \cap C \cap D| - |A \cap B \cap C \cap E| - |A \cap B \cap D \cap E| - |A \cap C \cap D \cap E| - |B \cap C \cap D \cap E| $$
$$ + |A \cap B \cap C \cap D \cap E| $$
I think at this point, I am now starting to pick up on a pattern.
Here is the complete Inclusion-Exclusion formula:
$$ P(\text{at least one } A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) - \sum_{i<j} P(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum_{i<j<k} P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k) - ... + (-1)^{n+1} P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n) $$
Where:

$P(X)$ represents the probability of event $X$
$A_i$ represents the $i$-th event
$\cap$ represents intersection

Based on the above expansions, it seems that:

$\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$ sums the probabilities of all individual events
$\sum_{i<j} P(A_i \cap A_j)$ subtracts the probabilities of all pairwise intersections
$\sum_{i<j<k} P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k)$ adds back the probabilities of all triple intersections
etc
This pattern continues, alternating between addition and subtraction
The final term $(-1)^{n+1} P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n)$ is the probability of all events occurring simultaneously, added if $n$ is odd or subtracted if $n$ is even

So this is basically alternating the addition and subtractions to prevent double counting the overlaps.
Is this the correct reasoning?

Correct.

First, the three circle areas are added together.  When the area of Lens DB is subtracted, that removes the white area from the first of the three circles.  When the area of Lens AF is subtracted, that removes the white area from the second of the three circles.  When the area of Lens EC is subtracted, that removes the white area from the third of the three circles.  However, now the white area isn't counted at all, so we have to add it in at the end to make sure it's counted once.  This principle repeats for additional iterations.
